# How can I print it out when data is added other than location.reload for localstorage?

Tags: javascript, local-storage, preload

I am storing the data with localstorage. But I have a problem like this. When a new data is added, that data does not appear before refreshing the page.

So, how can I print it out when data is added other than location.reload for localstorage?

// Add Button

```
                    <a style="cursor: pointer;" class="text-secondary  no-decoration" id="bookmark" data-id="<?= $this->detail->id; ?>" data-url="<?= $this->detail->articles_sef_link; ?>" data-date="<?= H::timeConvert($this->detail->created_at); ?>" data-title="<?= $this->detail->articles_title; ?>" data-img="<?= $this->detail->url; ?>" data-user="<?= $this->detail->fname;?> <?= $this->detail->lname; ?>" data-tooltip="Okunmadı olarak işaretle" data-tooltip-location="bottom"><i class="far fa-flag" style="font-size: 21px"></i></a>
```

// Add mark as read list
$('#bookmark').click(function(){

```
$('#iconHidden').hide();
$('#iconShow').show();

    // Get Information articles
    let id         = $(this).data("id");
    let sef_link   = $(this).data("url");
    let created_at = $(this).data("date");
    let title      = $(this).data("title");
    let img        = $(this).data("img");
    let fullname   = $(this).data("user");


    array_item.push({id,sef_link,created_at,title,img,fullname});
    localStorage.setItem("array_item", JSON.stringify(array_item));
    location.reload();


    //console.log(array_item);

});
```

Comment: please add minimal reproducible code to show us what you did and where you are stuck? it will be difficult here for people to interpret a few lines.

Comment: Try to add some `console.log` before and after setItem. Verify the dataset if it is correct and if it can be read directly after setItem. Because sometimes the DevTools doesn't update the localStorage but in code it works. Also have some kind of reference to the values so don't rely on the localStorage.

Comment: @Gkiokan There is no problem with the codes. Loading data. However, when I print out the data, I have to use the location.reload function. I say How can I display the added data without refreshing the page other than this function?

Comment: You need to modify your HTML directly to display the data. You are not doing that in your code. We also don't know anything else about the structure of your code. Can you make a jsFiddle with the elements that gets clicked and you want to update? Are you using vanilla JS or any framework that has double binded data? You can solve this problem with proper data handling without the need of a location.reload().

Comment: @Gkiokan 
I shared the button I use while uploading the data in the question. You are also talking about changing HTML codes; What did you mean about this topic?

Comment: Where is your data displayed? When adding the new data to your localstorage, you have to update your HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Codepen:**
[Codepen example: Dynamic content using local storage](https://codepen.io/michaelkonstreu/pen/jOqgjxr)

This is a code example. There are three buttons which add a new bookmark to your local storage. The fourth button clears the storage.

The bookmarks are listed in the table dynamically.

After clicking a button the function `addData` is called. This function adds the new bookmark to the local storage. After that, this function calls another function `updateTable`. `updateTable` updates the table content (element with the id `content`).
For this purpose it iterates through the `bookmark` array and calls `addTableRow` which adds a new table row to the table body for all bookmarks.

**Please notice:** In this solution I cleared the table content when adding a new bookmark to the local storage. But this depends on your specific needs. You could also simply append the new added bookmark to the table instead of deleting the old content and redraw the complete bookmark array.

**HTML:**

```
<button onclick="button1()">Add bookmark 1</button>
<button onclick="button2()">Add bookmark 2</button>
<button onclick="button3()">Add bookmark 3</button>
<button onclick="clearLocalStorage()">Clear local storage</button>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>Created</td>
      <td>Link</td>
      <td>Title</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="content">
    <!-- Dynamic content -->
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**CSS:**

```
table{
  margin-top: 40px;
  background: #dedede;
}

td{
  min-width: 100px;
}

thead > tr > td{
  font-weight:  bold;
}
```

**JS:**

```
function button1(){
  addData('01.01.1980', 'my-page.com', 'My page');
}
function button2(){
  addData('03.09.1990', 'your-page.com', 'Your page');
}
function button3(){
  addData('04.11.2010', 'our-page.com', 'Our page');
}

function clearLocalStorage(){
  localStorage.setItem("bookmarks", JSON.stringify([]));
  updateTable();
}

function addData(created, link, title){
  // Get bookmarks
  let bookmarks = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("bookmarks"));
  // When this object do not exist, create a new array
  if(bookmarks === undefined || bookmarks === null) bookmarks = new Array();
  console.log(bookmarks);
  bookmarks.push({created, link, title});
  // Save the new bookmark in the local storage
  localStorage.setItem("bookmarks", JSON.stringify(bookmarks));
  // Update the table which displays the bookmarks
  updateTable();
}

function updateTable(){
  // Get all bookmarks of the local storage
  let bookmarks = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("bookmarks"));
  console.log(bookmarks);
  // Get the DOM element which displays the bookmarks dynamically
  let content = document.getElementById('content');
  // Delete the current content
  content.innerHTML = '';
  // Iterate through the bookmark array and call the function
  // "addTableRow" for alle element in the array.
  bookmarks.forEach(bookmark => {
    addTableRow(content, bookmark);
  });
}

function addTableRow(content, data){
  // Create a new table row
  let newRow = document.createElement('tr');
  // Create new table cells
  let created = document.createElement('td');
  created.innerHTML = data.created;
  let link = document.createElement('td');
  link.innerHTML = data.link;
  let title = document.createElement('td');
  title.innerHTML = data.title;
  // Append the table cells to the row
  newRow.appendChild(created);
  newRow.appendChild(link);
  newRow.appendChild(title);
  // Append the table row to the content
  content.appendChild(newRow);
}
```